# JPA. Many to Many creates duplicated rows

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

please help me understand where I was wrong. 
I have three table:

Table Wishes

```sql
CREATE TABLE WISHES(
  wish_id bigint default nextval('wish_id_inc'::regclass),
  target text not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(wish_id)
)
```

Table TAGS

```sql
CREATE TABLE TAGS(
  tag character varying(255) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(tag)
)
```

Table Wish_tags

```sql
CREATE TABLE wish_tags(
  wish_tags bigint default nextval('wish_tags_id_inc'::regclass),
  wish_id bigint references wishes(wish_id),
  tag_id character varying(255) references tags(tag),
  PRIMARY KEY(wish_tags)
)
```

I created two classes for these tables:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="wishes")
public class Wish  implements Serializable{
...
      @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(
          name="wish_tags",
          joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="wish_id", referencedColumnName="wish_id")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="tag")})
    private List<Tag> tags;
...
}
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name="tags")
    public class Tag implements Serializable{
        ...
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags")
        private List<Wish> whishes;
        ...
    }
```

When i try to create wish with tags, i get duplicate into wish_tags table.

```java
@Transactional
public Wish createWish(List<String> tags){
//em is EntityManager
        ArrayList<Tag> ObTags = new ArraList<Tag>();
        for(String tagId: tags){
            Tag tag = new Tag(tagId);
            ObTags.add(em.merge(tag));
        }
        Wish wish = new Wish(args1,..., ObTags);
        em.persist(wish);
    }
```

What i do wrong? Why duplicate is created? Please, help me.

Comment: you can use @Column(insertable=false, updatable =false) property in either of ManyTOMany declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was my mistake in code. I put  the same tags twice into wish.

Answer (score 2):

Two tags are saved in DB because one is saved on `EntityManager.merge(tag)` and the other on cascading `EntityManager.persist(wish)` to `ObTags` collection.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it was my mistake in code, I put the same tags twice to ObTags. There is no any cascade for ObTags into Wish. As I can If I don't specify any cascade then hibernate should not save ObTags. It's true?